# Python: I am trying to match number but it is matching something else

Tags: python

```
import re

list = []
string = "[50,40]"
print(string)
for line in string.split(","):
  print(line)
  match = re.search(r'\d[0-9]', line)
  print(match)
  if match:
   list.append(match)
print("list is", list)
```

list is:

```
 [<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 3), match='50'>,
  <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='40'>]
```

I want to match only 40 and 50 and not some other useless info like

```
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 3),
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2),]
```

How to avoid other things and match only 40 and 50

Comment: Don't use builtin name `list` as variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.findall` function, it'll

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings

```
string = "[50,40]"
result = re.findall(r'\d+', string)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['50', '40']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code *is* matching the numbers, but you need to extract the strings from the Match objects. You can do that with the `.groups` method.

Here's a repaired version of your code. I've changed some of your names because you should not shadow the builtin `list` type, also `string` is the name of a standard module.

```
import re

lst = []
s = "[50,40]"
print(s)
for line in s.split(","):
    print(line)
    match = re.search(r'\d[0-9]', line)
    print(match)
    if match:
        lst.append(match.group(0))
print("list is", lst)
```

**output**

```
[50,40]
[50
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 3), match='50'>
40]
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='40'>
list is ['50', '40']
```

---

Your regex is a little strange. If you *only* want to match 2 digit numbers you could use `r'\d\d'` or `r'\d{2}'`. If you want to match any (non-negative) you should use `r'\d+'`.

And you really don't need to do that loop. Just use the `re.findall` method:

```
import re

s = "[50,40]"
lst = re.findall(r'\d+', s)
print("list is", lst)
```

If you intend to do lots of searches with the same pattern, it's a good idea to use a compiled regex. The `re` module compiles and caches all regexes anyway, but doing it explicitly is considered good style, and is a litle more efficient.

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'\d+')
s = "[50,40]"
lst = pat.findall(s)
print("list is", lst)
```